# Im making a simple text based python game for school, how do i incorporate a timer in it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def bear_room():
    print("\nthere's a bear here")
    print("\nthe bear has a bunch of honey")
    print("\nthe fat bear is front of another door")
    print("\nhow are you going to move the bear?")

    choice = input("\n\nTaunt bear, take honey, open door?: ")
    if choice == "take honey":
        print("\nthe bear looks at you then slaps your face off")
    elif choice == "open door":
        print("\nget the hell out")
    elif choice == "Taunt bear":
        print("\n*Bear rips your heart out*")
    else:
        print("\nInvalid entry")
        bear_room()


bear_room()
```

Im making a simple text based python game for school, how do i incorporate a timer in it?
i want it to be a 10 second countdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can introduce another function called `timer`. This function will use the time module in Python. The code for the timer is:

```
def timer(t):#t must be the time of the timer in seconds
    while t:
        mins,sec=divmod(t,60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end='\r')
        time.sleep(1)
        t=t-1
    print("Time's Up")
```

This code will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the countdown in seconds too while waiting, then @Shuvam Paul 's answer is the way to do it; but if you only need to wait for 10 seconds without doing anything else, then just the standard `time.sleep()` function is enough - that's what creates the pause.

```py
import time

def bear_room():
    print("\nthere's a bear here")
    print("\nthe bear has a bunch of honey")
    print("\nthe fat bear is front of another door")
    print("\nhow are you going to move the bear?")

    time.sleep(10) # Shift this line to wherever you want the 10 sec delay, if not here
    choice = input("\n\nTaunt bear, take honey, open door?: ")
    if choice == "take honey":
        print("\nthe bear looks at you then slaps your face off")
    elif choice == "open door":
        print("\nget the hell out")
    elif choice == "Taunt bear":
        print("\n*Bear rips your heart out*")
    else:
        print("\nInvalid entry")
        bear_room()

bear_room()
```